facing issue while uploading project it on render
enter image description here
this is my rander log screen
//navbar.ejs
  <% if(!currentUser) {%>
            <a class="nav-link"  href="/signup"><b>Sign Up</b></a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/login"><b>Log in</b></a>
          <% } %>
          <% if(currentUser) {%>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Log-out</a>
            <% } %>
//boilerplate
  <%- include("../includes/navbar.ejs") %>
    <div class="container">
        <%- include("../includes/flash.ejs") %>
        <%- body %>
    </div>
//using locals
app.use((req, res, next)=>{
   res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
   res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
   res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
   next();
});


currentUser is using locals and that is req.user
all this working in my local server but when i try to upload this on render this giving me error
why it is giving me error
enter image description here

The error message you're seeing is describing the problem.
Your code in navbar.ejs is trying to access a variable called currentUser which it doesn't have access to at that point in the code while rendering the page.
